# css on hover element shifts down in firefox only

Tags: html, css, position

http://webplio.com/web/app.php/register/

Hello, on that link, when hovering over the "add user" button, the + character seems to shift down on Firefox 29 nightly Linux by one pixel. On Chromium 32, it works fine. I've inspected the css and can't find anything obvious that would shift. Does anyone have an idea?

[image: top is in hover state, bottom is not hover state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class in there with a `:before` that is causing it from what I can see.

In `.flaticon.solid:before` remove the `line-height: 1;` and you should see the issue go away.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, but I'm not supposed to modify the flaticon css files since they're external assets.

Comment: hmm, can you add any CSS? You could add the `line-height:1` to `.flaticon.solid` class so that it's always there - just add that to a "cssOverrides" file